# Counting amount of times a mutation occurs in a .maf file

Tags: java, python, bioinformatics

I'm trying to count the number of mutations in a MAF file. I originally wrote this code in python and it worked perfectly fine, but when I translated it to Java it stopped working.  In the output file the number of mutations is always one. What am I doing wrong here?

```
package dev.suns.bioinformatics;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Main {

    static String filePath = "C:/Users/Matthew/Bioinformatics/Data Files/DLBC.maf";
    static String fileName = "DLBC_Info.txt";

public static void main(String[] args){
    createFile(filePath, fileName);
}

public static void createFile(String filePath, String fileName){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String delimiter = "\t";

    String geneSymbol = "";
    String newGene = "";
    int count;

    try {

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

        writer.println("Gene" + "\t" + "Mutations" + "\n");

        br.readLine();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            String[] splitFile = line.split(delimiter);
            newGene = splitFile[0];

            if(geneSymbol == ""){
                geneSymbol = newGene;   
            }

            else if(newGene == geneSymbol){
                #This is here I am having trouble. I have this if-statement to check if the gene appears more than once in the .maf file, but nothing is ever entering this.
                count++;
            }
            else{
                count++;
                writer.println(geneSymbol + "\t" + count + "\n");
                geneSymbol = newGene;
                count=0;
            }

        }
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what the first few lines of the file look like

Gene    Mutations

A1CF    1

A2M 1

A2M 1

A2ML1   1

A4GALT  1

AADAC   1

AADACL3 1

AAED1   1

AAGAB   1

AAGAB   1

AARD    1

AARS2   1

AARS2   1

AARS2   1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you need to compare strings using equals function. This should work-

```
else if(newGene.equals(geneSymbol)){
            #This is here I am having trouble. I have this if-statement to check if the gene appears more than once in the .maf file, but nothing is ever entering this.
            count++;
        }
```

"==" checks for the reference. whether they are same string objects. In order to compare values of string you need to use equals() function.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works. Click on the right button below down arrow. So it's clear to people that this question have been answered.

Comment: Oops sorry I'm new to stackoverflow